# No overload for method 'Given' takes 4 arguments - specflow

Tags: nuget, specflow

I have installed specflow. And by default I get this scenario to add two numbers. when I build the solution, i get these errors. "No overload for method 'Given' takes 4 arguments". What is that I am missing here? this is the generated file.

```
public virtual void AddTwoNumbers()
        {
            TechTalk.SpecFlow.ScenarioInfo scenarioInfo = new TechTalk.SpecFlow.ScenarioInfo("Add two numbers", new string[] {
                        "mytag"});
            #line 7
            this.ScenarioSetup(scenarioInfo);
            #line 8
             testRunner.Given("I have entered 50 into the calculator", ((string)(null)), ((TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table)(null)), "Given ");
            #line 9
             testRunner.And("I have entered 70 into the calculator", ((string)(null)), ((TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table)(null)), "And ");
            #line 10
             testRunner.When("I press add", ((string)(null)), ((TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table)(null)), "When ");
            #line 11
             testRunner.Then("the result should be 120 on the screen", ((string)(null)), ((TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table)(null)), "Then ");
            #line hidden

            this.ScenarioCleanup();
        }
```

For this scenario:

Feature: SpecFlowFeature1
    In order to avoid silly mistakes
    As a math idiot
    I want to be told the sum of two numbers

@mytag
Scenario: Add two numbers
    Given I have entered 50 into the calculator
    And I have entered 70 into the calculator
    When I press add
    Then the result should be 120 on the screen

Comment: Can you post the code where you get the compilation error? Because the default generated Given: `[Given("I have entered (.*) into the calculator")]` should compiling fine.

Comment: It seems you are using an old version of the `TechTalk.SpecFlow` dll What is the version of your `TechTalk.SpecFlow` dll? Because it should be 1.9.0. to be able work. Have you installed it with the nuget http://nuget.org/packages/SpecFlow?

Comment: I did not install it using commands, but downloaded the dll and added the reference. and its version is 1.8.1.0. Do I have to install anything else? Is it necessary to install nuget package through commands?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was a problem of techtalk.specflow.dll version. I had 1.8.1 version which I replaced with 1.9.0 and everything worked ! Thank u for ur suggestions

Comment: This solution worked for me. I had installed the specflow.nunit package.....it turns out that this it out of date so I had to download the actual specflow package itself afterwards to update TechTalk.Specflow.

Comment: For all the people following SpecFlow's getting started documentation, after you install it, go to nuget package and upgrade it to 1.9 version